# Why does the CheckerFramework say error: [dereference.of.nullable] for a variable that it knows is not null?

Tags: java, checker-framework

Here is a sample constructor for a class called `UIMenus`:

```
1   UIMenus() {
2     PropertyChangeListener focusListener = evt -> {
3       Component focusOwner = (Component) evt.getNewValue();
4       //noinspection ObjectEquality
5       if (focusOwner != caretOwner) {
6         if (caretOwner != null) {
7           caretOwner.removeCaretListener(this); // Checker Frame knows caretOwner isn't null here.
8 
9           // error: [dereference.of.nullable] dereference of possibly-null reference caretOwner
10          final String text = caretOwner.getText();
11          System.out.printf("deFocus c with %s to %s%n",
12              text, (focusOwner == null) ? "None" : focusOwner.getClass().toString());
13        }
14        if (focusOwner instanceof JTextComponent) {
15          // focusOwner can't be null, so caretOwner can't get set to null here.
16          caretOwner = (JTextComponent) focusOwner;
17          caretOwner.addCaretListener(this);
18
19          // error: [dereference.of.nullable] dereference of possibly-null reference caretOwner
20          final String text = caretOwner.getText();
21          System.out.printf("Focus c with %s%n", text);
22        }
23      }
24    };
25    focusManager.addPropertyChangeListener("permanentFocusOwner", focusListener);
26  }
```

On lines 10 and 20, I'm getting a `dereference.of.nullable` error. But each statement is inside
an `if` block and has been tested for null. Furthermore, each has been already dereferenced on
the previous line. So on line 7, the checker framework knows that caretOwner is not null, but
not on line 10. The same is true of lines 17 and 20. It seems to me that the null checker should
know that the value is not null for the rest of the `if` block, but that's not what I'm seeing.
Am I misunderstanding something about how the null checker works? Or is this a bug?

For a reproducible test case, see the UIMenus class at https://github.com/SwingGuy1024/CheckerQuestions